# Windows 10 backup stuck at 97%

Tags: windows-10, backup, external-hard-drive

I was backing up my ssd to an external usb hard drive, and it was almost over being done. It says Creating a system image of windows (C:) but its stuck there for an hour. The green bar thingy is also moving, means no crashes. I opened file explorer and went to the hard drive and the partition was still there. Also before i tried to create system image but it always failed. What should I do?

Comment: https://www.ubackup.com/articles/windows-backup-freezes-at-97-8523.html

Comment: If no solution use a third party backup software like Macrium Reflect Free.

Comment: Windows 10 backup is deprecated, don't use it.

Comment: @harrymc While that may be the case, it seems to be the only built-in tool that creates full disk images, right? I suppose ultimately I would want a FOSS solution, but I haven't found one yet.

Comment: @TwistedCode: This post is 2 years old. You might try at https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/